# cbp2make linking libraries with ".a" on windows

Tags: windows, makefile, codeblocks, mingw32

I am trying to generate a makefile from a codeblock project file ".cbp" with the cbp2make tool on windows. But the generated makefile has unix format archive libraries  :

LIB = libkernerl32.a libuser32.a libgdi32.a

, which causes issues when trying to use mingw32-make.exe, it complains that libkernerl32.a is missing

When I compile through codeblock I see in the build log that it uses -lkernerl32 luser32 -lgdi32.

I looked at the project.cbp in a text editor and noticed that under  there is :
 etc ...

So I assume codeblock changes those from libkernel32.a to -lkernel32 when building, which cbp2make does not seem to do when generating the makefile.

I run : cbp2make.exe -in project.cbp -out makefile -windows

How can I get cbp2make to have :
 LIB = -lkernel32 -luser32 
Instead of
 LIB = libkernel32.a libuser32.a
?

Comment: What issues are you actually having? That `LIB` line is perfectly reasonable if it is used as a list of library files to build/package/etc. (assuming they actually exist, with those names, on Windows). The argument to `-l` for the linker is the library basename (i.e. without the `lib` prefix and without a file extension). So `-lkernel32` can use either of `libkernel32.so` or `libkernel32.a` (and possibly `libkernel32.dll` on Windows I'm not sure).

Comment: The issue is that ".a" don't exist on Windows , they are usually ".lib" if I'm not mistaken, so when I "make" it fails because "libkernel32.a" simply does not exist on a windows machine, it should , at best be looking for a ".lib". I want the cb2make tool to generate the makefile with -lkernel32 instead of libkernel32.a

Comment: My point was that that line probably isn't (though it could be) specifying the `-l` arguments to the linker. You can use a bare filename with the linker but many times you don't do that. I'm not suggesting that line isn't wrong for Windows, it might very well be, I'm just not sure that's the actual issue you are having (since you didn't actually tell us what that issue is).

Comment: Oh sorry, no , the issue isn't with specifying the filename. I guess it could be "kernel32.lib" and it would compile no problem. But since I want the makefile to work on windows not linux, the cbp2make should not generate a makefile with ".a" library extensions, but rather ".lib". It's an issue with the generation of the makefile.

Comment: You are missing the point. You keep telling us you want that but you haven't told us what the file having the "wrong" names is actually breaking for you. You implied it is breaking things but didn't give us an error message or anything. That's what I keep trying to find out... What (using the makefiles with `.a` in them) is broken when you try to build using them?

Comment: Windows static libraries extension is ".lib" , unix static library extensions is ".a". I am compiling on windows and windows only. kernel32 and user32 are native windows libraries. The error : " it complains that libkernerl32.a is missing". It is ok with me, my question is How can I get cbp2make.exe to generate a makefile that has : LIB = -lkernel32 -luser32 Instead of LIB = libkernel32.a libuser32.a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cbp2make` behaves somewhat differently to `CodeBlocks` when generating linking argument line.

`CodeBlocks` will automatically add `-l` (`link_library_switch`), remove `lib` (`library_prefix`) prefix and remove extension for static linking libraries listed with (at least) `a` extension (managed to test only that case). For dynamic linking libraries the extension of `so` it will not be removed.

`cb2make` on the other hand is not so smart. It does not automatically remove the `lib` prefix nor the extension (at lest at `rev 147`). However what it does underneath (`cbproject.cpp:790`) is it checks whether a library is specified with an extension.

**If extension is present**, it will simply copy-paste the library entry, preserving it's path (if given). **If**, on the other hand, **the extension is not present**, it will assume that the user did not give a full path to the lib, but instead wants the linker to search for it. It will prefix the library name with `-l` but it will not remove the `lib` prefix automatically (which at least for `g++` does not matter).

So to make sure both `CodeBlocks` and `cbp2make` are able to link in a similar manner I'd recommend:

- Do not prefix the library name with `lib` i.e. use `pthread` instead of `libpthread`,
- Do not suffix the library name with extension i.e. use `pthread` instead of `pthread.so`,
- It does not matter if the extension is a known library extension type. If you have a library named `libfoo.bar.baz.so` you're screwed and have to correct the `Makefile` manually,
- Optionally: Do not give the full (relative) path to the library.

**Also please note**: `link_library_switch` and `library_prefix` are compiler/linker/platform dependant. Please consult `cbp2make` configuration file for more information (`cbp2make.cfg`).

Generally speaking `cbp2make` is not handling this very well, despite having all the platform/compiler specific details in the configuration file and internal data structures.